# Pandas apply cell value to geonamescache function / Large file

Tags: python, pandas, geonames

novice here. I would like to:

Loads CSV (4,5mln rows) - done

Assign columns - done

Create a new column "Search"- done

Apply a function to Search so that it checks if the city name is in the list of cities from geonamescache. geonamescache has the get_cities_by_name() which should take name argument, return a dictionary with data or none if not found. I am having problem passing the name as argument to pandas apply. Any suggestions welcome.

```
import geonamescache
import pandas as pd

gc = geonamescache.GeonamesCache()
cities = gc.get_cities_by_name()


dtypes_dict = {
    0: int, # geonameid
    1: str,  # name
    2: str,  # asciiname
    3: str,  # alternatenames
    4: float, # latitude
    5: float, # longitude
    6: str, # feature class
    7: str, # feature code
    8: str, # country code
    9: str, # cc2
    10: str, # admin1 code
    11: str, # admin2 code
    12: str, # admin3 code
    13: str, # admin4 code
    14: int, # population
    15: int, # elevation
    16: int, # dem (digital elevation model)
    17: str, # timezone
    18: str # modification date yyyy-MM-dd
}

df = pd.read_csv('12.txt', sep = '\t', header = None, quoting = 3,  iterator=True, chunksize=100, engine='python', dtype=dtypes_dict, names = ['geonameid', 'name', 'asciiname', 'alternatenames', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'feature_class', 'feature_code', 'country_code', 'cc2', 'admin1_code', 'admin2_code', 'admin3_code', 'admin4_code', 'population', 'elevation', 'dem', 'timezone', 'modification_date'])


df["Search"] = df['asciiname'].apply(cities())

df.to_csv("GeoSearch.txt")
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/u6022697/Documents/python work/5pandas.py", line 5, in <module>
    cities = gc.get_cities_by_name()
TypeError: get_cities_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error. It tells you that you need to pass name to `get_cities_by_name`. Look at your code:

```
cities = gc.get_cities_by_name()
```

see that there is no name passed to the function which expects a name to be passed. Try

```
cities = gc.get_cities_by_name("New York")
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, but ideally I would like to take "New York" from "aciiname" column, (from dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant but I'm also working with geonamescache at the moment so I was able to come across this question. But for anyone who's looking for this as well, unfortunately, they don't have a feature like that where you can pass along a list for the get_cities_by_name() method as it expects a single name based on the [definition](https://github.com/yaph/geonamescache/blob/master/geonamescache/__init__.py#L63) You would have to invoke this method in a for loop or something alike in order to use it for the whole column.